# Swift Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a newbie to swift and for now it's a pain in the a$$ to code.
I'm trying to make a very simple app where the user enters a number to a textfield
and then when a button is clicked it shows the number + 1 in a label.
I always get this error:

> Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1002c11ec)

This is my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tav: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fogy: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eredmeny: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var szamolasBtn: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func szamol(_ sender: Any) {
        let number = Int(tav.text!)! + 1
        eredmeny.text = String(describing: number)
    }

    }
```

Comment: Any exclamation mark could cause the error. Not related, but all unspecified `sender`s of `IBAction` in Swift 3 are `AnyObject`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it works fine if an integer in entered in the textfield. But if you enter any character other than a string then the app crashes because **Int(tav.text!)!** returns **nil** and adding 1 to **nil**. Check for **nil** first and then add something to it.